# how to retry an entire poller flow in Spring-Integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I‘ve  been pulling my hairs on how to implement the retry pattern (retry the WHOLE flow) for a Spring-Integration poller flow.
Please find below my (erroneous) source-code (doesn't work).

What am I doing wrong ?
(if I put a breakpoint on the line throwing an exception, it's only hit once）

thanks a lot in advance for your time and your expertise.

Best Regards

nkjp

PS: maybe try to extend AbstractHandleMessageAdvice with a RetryTemplate ?

```
return IntegrationFLows.from(SOME_QUEUE_CHANNEL)  
.transform(p -> p, e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)  
    .advice(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().maxAttempts(5).backOffOptions(1,2,10).build())))  
.transform(p -> {  
  if (true) {
    throw new RuntimeException("KABOOM");
  }
  return p;
})
.channel(new NullChannel())
.get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `poller.advice()`, then an `Advice` is applied to the whole flow starting with `poll()` method. Since you have already polled a message from that queue, there is nothing to poll from it on the next attempt. It is kinda anti-pattern to use retry for non-transactional queues: you don't rollback transactions so your data doesn't come back to store to be available for the next `poll()`.

There is no way at the moment to retry a whole sub-flow from some point, but you definitely can use a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` on the specific erroneous endpoint like that your `transform()` with `KABOOM` exception:

```
.transform(p -> {
                        if (true) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("KABOOM");
                        }
                        return p;
                    }, e -> e.advice(new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice()))
```

See its `setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate retryTemplate)` for more retry options instead of just 3 attempts by default.

To make for a sub-flow, we need to consider to implement a `HandleMessageAdvice`.
Something like this:

```
.transform(p -> p, e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500000))
                            .advice(new HandleMessageAdvice() {

                                RetryOperationsInterceptor delegate =
                                        RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                                                .maxAttempts(5)
                                                .backOffOptions(1, 2, 10)
                                                .build();

                                @Override
                                public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
                                    return delegate.invoke(invocation);
                                }
                            }))
```

But again: it's not a `poller` advice., it is an endpoint one on its `MessageHandler.handleMessage()`.

Comment: Maybe we should consider adding a version of `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` that is a subclass of `AbstractHandleMessageAdvice` to advise the whole downstream flow?

Comment: We decided to do something out-of-the-box: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3219

Comment: As always, thanks a lot to both of you Gary and Artem for taking time to answer end-user questions like mine ! Following your advice, I hacked something with AbstractHandleMessageAdvice and RetryTemplate which seems to fullfil my needs.
thanks again for your prompt feedback !